# Can I not use the pronoun "I"?

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns, conversation

Is it possible not to use the pronoun "I" when it occurs very often?
For example, there are sentences:

*I will have breakfast now. Then I will go for a walk. Then I will go to sleep.*

Is it possible to write/speak like this:

*I will have breakfast now. Then _ will go for a walk. Then _ will go to sleep.*

That is, it is clear that this is about me and I don’t want to use the pronoun "I" too often, because in my language it is not modest and testifies to egocentricity. What about English?

Comment: No, but you can say "I will have breakfast, then go for a walk, then go to sleep." Not because repeating 'I' is immodest, just to avoid repeating the same form of words.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you very much! It is interesting.